# В чем фундаментальная разница var let в данном случае

Tags: javascript

```
var x = document.createElement('button');

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  x.addEventListener('click', function (e) {
    console.log(i)
  })
}
x.click()
```

Выведет три тройки `3/3/3`
Но если подставить в цикл `(let i = 0; i < 3; i++)`
Выевед `0/1/2`

Много перегуглил, но почему мы получаем при `var` первый раз 3,

Что запускаетя раньше цикл или функция клика?

Comment: вот [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/762011/whats-the-difference-between-using-let-and-var) вы найдете ответ на ваш вопрос, там всё подробно расписано

Answer (score 0, accepted):

это просто, вам нужно разобраться с контекстом. а в данном случае

let - объявляет контекстную (локальную) переменную

var - глобальную

на счет почему  console.log(i) вызывает 3/3/3 потому что функции передана глобальная переменная, а её вызов произойтет только когда Event Loop получит доступ  (выполнение) к этому коду, а к этому моменту i уже будет = 3.

на счет почему  console.log(i) вызывает 0/1/2 потому что функции передана значение локальной переменной, а её вызов произойтет только когда Event Loop получит доступ  (выполнение) к этому коду, но она не меняется в контексте другого вызова.