# использование addEventListener на массив

Tags: javascript, addeventlistener

Делаю пародию игры морской бой с помощью django, добавляю сетку поля на сайт с помощью js и мне надо сделать так что бы каждый элемент этой сетки был своей определенной кнопкой. У каждого квадрата данной сетки есть свой уникальный id и когда я делаю из квадрата кнопку (без цикла то все работает):

```
findP3[0].addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        alert(findP3[0].id);
    }, false);
```

FindP3 это массив хранящий элементы данной сетки, но как только я пытаюсь сделать так с помощью цикла что бы сделать сразу для всех элементов то получаются проблемы:

```
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    findP3[i].addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        alert(findP3[i].id);
    }, false);
}
```

то я получаю проблему в консоли:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'id')
    at HTMLDivElement.<anonymous> (createField.js:43:26)
```

Я попытался в alert писать:

```
 alert(findP3[i-1].id);
```

Ошибка ушла но теперь при нажатии на каждый элемент я получаю айди только блока 99.

А как мне сделать так что бы каждый блок был отдельной кнопкой и выводил свое айди при нажатии?

Вот весь код:

```
console.log("createField file connected successfully")
function getNumber (theStr) {
var theNumber = "";
for (var i = 0; i < theStr.length; i++)
    {
        if (Number(theStr.charAt(i))) {
            theNumber += theStr.charAt(i);

        }
    }
return theNumber;
}

let findP = document.getElementById("battleFieldBlocks");
//let myElement = document.createElement('p');
let FieldsArr = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    var blockTemp = document.createElement('div')
    blockTemp.id = "block"+i;
    blockTemp.className = "theBlock"
    FieldsArr.push(blockTemp);
}


for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    findP.append(FieldsArr[i]);
}
let findP3 = [];
var findTemp;
for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    findTemp = document.getElementById("block" + i);
    findP3.push(findTemp);
}

for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    findP3[i].addEventListener("click", function (e) {
        alert(findP3[i].id);
    }, false);
}
```

P.S
C самими элементами проблем нет, всем присвоились правильные ID, я подозреваю что проблема именно с циклом

Comment: Цикл - правильное решение...... properties of undefined значит у элемента нет свойства id. Продебажь, посмотри элементы на нужные свойства, количество и пр

Comment: Кстати, в цикле используй не `var`, а `let`. В этом проблема текущего цикла и навешивания слушателей у тебя

Comment: А в чём проблема сделать типа такого: `document.querySelectorAll('theBlock').forEach(() => { /* Что-то сделать для всех блоков */ })`?

Comment: @АлексейШиманский есть у всех елементов айди я уже проверил проблема с циклом. Не надо пожалуйста закрывать вопрос с сылкой на другой stackoverflow который не имеет отношения к моему вопросу

Comment: @leocoolguy0 Вполне себе имеет. Чтобы найти ошибку в своём коде, достаточно отладчиком по нему пробежаться и разобраться что происходит на каждой строчке кода........ Как бы то ни было я уже подсказал в чём состоит проблема

Comment: @АлексейШиманский Это понял, спасибо) просто тогда можно на эту ссылку абсолютно любой вопрос перевешить, мол сами смотрите и дебажьте)) сейчас буду пробовать с let и var менять как вы и сказали

Comment: "мол сами смотрите и дебажьте" --- так и есть. Если проблема в коде типа "у меня где-то тут ошибка, не могу понять" или "внезапно что-то не работает", то разработчик идёт дебажить свой код. Тут никакой хитрости нет. Любой разраб должен владеть этим инструментом и часто с ним и сидит, а не код пишет))  Если вопрос, условно: "как ускорить код", или специфика языка - окей. Но "не работает код" - однозначно отладка

Comment: @АлексейШиманский А можете объяснить пожалуйста почему возникает проблема из за var в цикле? цикл же в любом случае перебирается?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1145811/191482  .........в целом надо ваам почитать разницу между var и let....... и вообще лучше забыть про var навсегда